# kakfa ordering issue example and need input

Tags: apache-kafka

I have issue for producing the message in the order for kafka producer topic. I ensured that my data is all go to appropriate partition based on the key.

Product 1 is in partition 1 and key as “A”
Product 2 is in partition 2 and key as “B”.

Product group 1 is made of product 1 and product 2. and key for this “C” and landed into partition 3.

When consumer is trying to consume the data, product group 1 gets consumed before product 1 and product 2 as product group is different partition. We ended having a failure now.

I tried to research as much as possible and not easy way of handling the ordering issue.  Anyone come across this product ?

I was trying to use the product group id is the partition key for product 1 and product 2. But product 1 and product 2 has no information about the product group.

It will be great if there is any solution available to resolve on the producer side. If not what are all the option available in the consumer side to handle it ? easy way to do. I did stack overflow research too and cant find any better solution.

Kafka ordering happening with in the partition level and not across the partition. We don’t want to go with single partition approach.

Any help would be appreciated.

1. i did try by working out the key based solution where all the data resides in one partition and didnt work.
2. are there any other approach we can use with kakfa state store? not able to think.
3. each consumer can read and write the message, then order the data on their own like staging that's too much work.
4. are there any approach we can use ksql to pull the data of product and load before we process the product group.?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you mean by "product group".

Comment: Multiple product linked to one product group. it is similar to user group where multiple user belongs to the user group.

Comment: These are not Kafka terms, though. Please edit your post to give example records, inputs and expected outputs. If they are different products in the same group, why does ordering matter? And you dont seem to need ordering over different groups.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka topic partitioning is mainly for parallelizing and increasing the throughput from the consumer side mainly.

Kafka doesn't guarantee ordering across multi-partition topic, it can only guarantee ordering within the partition, and it is totally under the control of the producer to handle key/custom partitioning and the consumer has to be fully aware of that in order to avoid your problem.

In your case, if you need the products to be processed in the order it is pushed with [prodcut-1 , product-2 , product-gp-1], then the straightforward and clean way is that they are pushed to the same exact partition, other than that you will create another problem to solve, which is reordering the data in a multi-threaded processing (be aware to be under the [XY-Problem dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem))

A good read about [kafka topic partitions](https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-choose-number-topics-partitions-kafka-cluster/)

Also [kafka arch official](https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation/streams/architecture) docs would help

Comment: As written in the question - _[tried] solution where all the data resides in one partition and didnt work_ + _We don’t want to go with single partition approach_

Comment: @OneCricketeer valid points